# Event vs no Event Action in C#?

Tags: c#, events, action

In general, I want to know, what is the effect of the `event` keyword behind the action and what is the difference between it and action without event and what feature does it add?

**Hint**: Please answer this question like this, because I did not find exactly that.

```cs
public event Action action; // event action

public Action action; // action
```

Comment: Here's a link to some documentation that will give you the information you're looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event

Comment: One is an event and one isn't. If you understand events and delegates then you understand what that means. If you don't understand what that means then you don't understand events and delegates, so that's what you need to research. That's the point. You claim that you aren't asking about something that we would be required to explain in order to answer your question in any detail, so you are asking about that. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Look at this to see what the compiler makes out of an event: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZRwzoCGAxgC4CWA9gHYDchxa6ApgG7fNamclTpNmMdkmIlMAFnQBZABQBKfBxlFNWnQF9keoA=

Comment: @SomeBody Thanks, this was very helpful. At least showed that the two keywords add and remove in the event are configurable.

Comment: See https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `public Action action;` you have a public delegate. It can be reassigned anywhere, which may be dangerous. When you declare `public event Action action;` you have a class with a hidden delegate field, and the class exposes only some functionality of delegates; in particular you can only attach and detach methods to it using `+=` and `-=`, but not outright reassign using `=`. To clarify what this means: suppose you have the following code:

```
using System;

class Worker
{ 
  public Action action;

  public void DoWork() {
    action();
  }
}

static class Test
{  
  public static void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
  }

  public static void Main() {
    Worker w = new Worker();
    w.action = Foo;
    w.DoWork();
  }
}
```

The class `Worker` has a public delegate named `action`.  In `Main` we create a new instance `w` and make its `action` point to the method `Foo`. Later we may reassign it by saying something like `w.action = Bar`. This may be seen as dangerous.

If the field `action` of class `Worker` were defined instead as `event`, i.e. `public event Action action;` then a direct assignment such as `w.action = Foo` would be illegal. Instead we can *attach* a particular handler to the event using `+=`. The following then works:

```
using System;

class Worker
{ 
  public event Action action;

  public void DoWork() {
    action();
  }
}

static class Test
{  
  public static void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
  }

  public static void Main() {
    Worker w = new Worker();
    w.action += Foo;
    w.DoWork();
  }
}
```

Comment: This was a good example and the answer I was looking for, so thank you so much. Unfortunately, most of my programming problems are due to my non-academic background.